# Setting the X and Y coordinates of a UIelement within a Canvas progmatically

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, wpf-controls

Admins: sorry if I asked this on the wrong forum, I'm new to the whole SE network.

I've been working on a project for some time now, and now I'm stuck. The project is a Universal Windows 8.1 runtime app programmed in C# and XAML. Below is a function from the Windows 8.1 part of the project called updateMapGUI(). It is called after an event is triggered and adds items to a pre-existing canvas on the page.

```
private void updateMapGUI()
{
    while (mapCanvas.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        mapCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    panelTracker = 0;
    foreach (User i in activeUsers)
    {
        if(i == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Update the mapCanvas with data from the appropriate User object from the array activeUsers[]
            dotpanels[panelTracker] = new Canvas();
            mapCanvas.Children.Add(dotpanels[panelTracker]);
            dotpanels[panelTracker].Height = 3;
            dotpanels[panelTracker].Width = 3;
            dotpanels[panelTracker].Left = getXOffset(i);
            dotpanels[panelTracker].Up = getYOffset(i);
            if (i.isSelected == false)
            {
                SolidColorBrush unselectedDot = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
                dotpanels[panelTracker].Background = unselectedDot;
            }
            else
            {
                SolidColorBrush selectedDot = new   SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
                dotpanels[panelTracker].Background = selectedDot;
            }
            panelTracker++;
        }
    }
}
```

dotpanels is a canvas[] array and panelTracker is an int[] array. The issue is with dotpanels[panelTracker].Left and dotpanels[panelTracker].Up. According to the documentation, this function can be called on any child of a canvas (not quite sure if I read that correctly). The compiler says that the Canvas in dotpanels[panelTracker] does not contain a definition for Up or Left. What am I doing wrong? If it's not possible, what I basically need to do is show some dots at specific X and Y locations. Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Look into adding Transforms on your canvas objects. They have TranslateX and TranslateY properties that will help you out.

Comment: How would I go about that? The only examples I can find are about using it in reverse to find a point. (Sorry about my noob questions, I'm new to the whole XAML and WinRT stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` (not `Up`) are [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758282.aspx), which are accessed in code via static getter and setter methods:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(dotpanels[panelTracker], getXOffset(i));
Canvas.SetTop(dotpanels[panelTracker], getYOffset(i));
```